# How do I print, identified as an AD user, from an Ubuntu client to a Windows print server?

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, samba, printing

I know my question may be confusing, so I'll clarify.

I'm an admin at a school and am setting up the labs to use Ubuntu (12.04). Users already can authenticate against Active Directory (currently using Likewise Open) for logins from any desktop client, and can access file and print shares on the Windows Server (2008R2). Clients can browse the Windows server for printers, install the drivers, and print. Until the end of the next school year, we will not have money or work hours available to set up a Linux print server, so we *must* go through the existing Windows Server for printing and auth.

The requirement that is causing difficulty is that when the user prints, the AD account of the user currently logged into the Ubuntu client *must* be identified as the one sending the print request, not some proxy admin account. This is because we have an accounting script that tallies print jobs sent per user so we can bill them at the end of each semester.

So far I can only set up a printer on an Ubuntu client if I use an admin user listed in AD. The problem is that the admin user is charged for all printing from the Ubuntu client from that point on. While that might be fun as a practical joke on one of my techs, it's not very useful.